# How to change the name of a listing on the Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I just published an item on the Chrome Web Store and at the time I could not change the name. Is there a way I can do this? Is it in the ZIP file I uploaded? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the name in your manifest. Just make sure you update the version number as well.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot that all that information was in the manifest.